# what is the return value of BeautifulSoup.find?

Tags: regex, beautifulsoup

I run to get some value as score.

```
score = soup.find('div', attrs={'class' : 'summarycount'})
```

I run 'print score' to get as follows.

```
<div class=\"summarycount\">524</div>
```

I need to extract the number part. I used re module but failed.

```
m = re.search("[^\d]+(\d+)", score)
```

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer

function search in re.py at line 142
return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
```

- What's the return type of the find function?
- How to get the number from the score variable?
- Is there any easy way to let BeautifulSoup to return the value(in this case 524) itself?

Comment: Sorry, can't resist... The correct return value should be "cheddar cheese"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It returns an object, which you can use for further searches or to extract its contents with `score.contents`:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

str = r'''
    <body>
    <div class="summarycount">524</div>
    <div class="foo">111</div>
    </body>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(str)
score = soup.find('div', attrs={'class' : 'summarycount'})

print type(score)
print score.contents
```

Prints:

```
<class 'BeautifulSoup.Tag'>
[u'524']
```

The full documentation with multiple examples is [available here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html).